How to use spaces by default instead of tabs
VSCode opens new files in Tabs mode (bottom status line shows "Tab Size") even though I have setting "Insert Spaces" on and "Detect Indentation" off. How can I change this?

Workspace-Specific settings (VS Code)
Check if you have .vscode/settings.json in your project folder.
.vscode/settings.json file:
{
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 3
}

.editorconfig file
This file can exist at the root of your project (for project-specific settings) or in your user's home directory (for user-wide preferences).
This can override any editor-specific settings and enforce consistent indentation rules across all supported editors and IDEs.
.editorconfig file:
# .editorconfig
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 3

